# Interested in changing how Microsoft ASP.NET Controls render HTML tags

Tags: asp.net, html, html-rendering

I'm using Microsoft .NET Framework Version 4.0 SP1Rel with Visual STudio 2010 Version 10 SP1Rel.
The Web application that my team is developing uses tags like  `<asp:Login/>`, `<asp:TemplateField/>`, `<asp:GridView/>` tags blah blah blah.....

It's pretty poor practice when microsoft .NET framework tags render HTML `<table>` tags.

How could I have more control as to how the microsoft .NET framework renders these HTML tags?  I obviously would want to use divs as opposed to tables.  May I please know how I can have more say as to how I would like the Microsoft ASP.NET Controls to render HTML tags?

Comment: Which controls? They've gotten much better since .NET 1.1. If you don't like most of the rendered html, use ASP.NET MVC instead.

Comment: .Net 4? Then don't use controls..i.e. Razor? [Create your own HTML helpers](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/views/creating-custom-html-helpers-cs)? As @jrummell has stated, it's been a long time since 1.1...

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't like it, you can do it yourself with a [Custom Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt27tfhy.aspx).

But I'd think twice before re-inventing .NET wheels.

Answer (score 0):

Use [Control adapters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163543.aspx) or better switch to ASP.NET MVC if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Most non tabular controls have an option to render as `<li>` or `<div>` instead of `<table>`.

`<asp:GridView>` is  tablular, so it makes a lot of sense to use a table, but if you want more control over the output, you could use `<asp:Repeater>` instead.

However, if you want full control over the generated html markup, ASP.NET WebForms isn't the best option. [ASP.NET MVC](http://asp.net/mvc) is much more flexible in this regard.